# How to change color of selected row in UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

Ok, maybe I'm missing something really simple and I apologize if that's the case, however, I've googled every permutation of the title and have not found!  So this is simply what I want to do:  change the background color of the label I'm using as the row view in a 2 component pickerview when that row has been selected.  So I thought this would work:

```
if (row == [pickerview selectedRowForComponent])
    viewlabel.backgroundColor = redcolor;
```

but this doesn't work.  It seems to arbitrarily choose which row to color and sometimes even give a bad access error.  I've tried all different clauses to no effect!  ANy suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!

Here's the full method:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{

    if (component == kNumberComponent) {


#define PICKER_LABEL_FONT_SIZE 24
#define PICKER_LABEL_ALPHA 1.0
        // UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:PICKER_LABEL_FONT_SIZE];
        UIFont *font = [ UIFont fontWithName:@"AppleGothic"  size:24];
        UILabel *carsLabel =[ [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 75, 50) ]autorelease];
        //[picker selectRow:row inComponent:component animated:YES];
        NSString *pickerText = [self.numbers objectAtIndex:(int)row];
        carsLabel.text = pickerText;
        carsLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        NSLog(@"carsLabel = %@",carsLabel.text);
        //carsLabel.text = @"maybe because the string isn't long enough";
        carsLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        carsLabel.font = font;





        carsLabel.opaque = YES;


        [view addSubview:carsLabel];

        return carsLabel;   
    } else {
        UIFont *font = [ UIFont fontWithName:@"AppleGothic"  size:18];

        UILabel *carsLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 225, 50)] autorelease];
        id fact = [self.facts objectAtIndex:(int)row];
        NSString *pickerText = @"Dictionary Entry";
        if ( [fact isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {


            pickerText = [self.facts objectAtIndex:(int)row];

        } 
        carsLabel.text = pickerText;
        carsLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        NSLog(@"carsLabel = %@",carsLabel.text);
        //carsLabel.text = @"maybe because the string isn't long enough";
        carsLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        carsLabel.font = font;
        if ( row == 0) {
        carsLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

        }
        //carsLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blackboard.png"]];;
        carsLabel.opaque = YES;

        [view addSubview:carsLabel];

        return carsLabel;
    }


    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved!  Declare 2 instance variables: selectedView, and oldView.  Then the following code does the trick:

```
if (self.oldView != nil)
        self.oldView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

self.selectedView = [picker viewForRow:row forComponent:kNumberComponent];
        self.selectedView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [self.selectedView setNeedsDisplay];
        self.oldView = self.selectedView;
```

Comment: In the UIPickerView's `viewForRow` method

Answer (score 10):

Normally, I use this method:

I use the custom view for show the row item

```
-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{

    UILabel *label = (id)view;

    if (!label)
    {

        label= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component].width, [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component].height)];
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        label.text = _arrayStringPicker[row];

    }  

    return label;
```

I change color of row selected with:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    UILabel *labelSelected = (UILabel*)[pickerView viewForRow:row forComponent:component];
    [labelSelected setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];

}
```

Answer (score 8):

Swift implementation

```
extension PickerViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate {
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
        var color: UIColor!
        if pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(component) == row {
            color = UIColor.redColor()
        } else {
            color = UIColor.blackColor()
        }

        let attributes: [String: AnyObject] = [
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color,
            NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)
        ]

        return NSAttributedString(string: rows[row], attributes: attributes)
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        //this will trigger attributedTitleForRow-method to be called
        pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The correct format for viewForPicker is:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UILabel *label = (UILabel*) view;
    if (label == nil)
    {
        label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    }

    [label setText:@"Whatever"];

    // This part just colorizes everything, since you asked about that.

    [label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    CGSize rowSize = [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component];
    CGRect labelRect = CGRectMake (0, 0, rowSize.width, rowSize.height);
    [label setFrame:labelRect];

    return label;
}
```

The problem with the code above is: it colorizes the labels, but not the picker, itself.  So, when you roll to one end or the other, there's a blank spot where you can see the white background.  Setting [myPicker setBackgroundColor...] doesn't do what one might hope.

Answer (score 4):

Swift version of @alessandro-pirovano answer

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {

    let rowSize = pickerView.rowSize(forComponent: component)
    let width = rowSize.width
    let height = rowSize.height
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
    let label = UILabel(frame: frame)
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.text = rows[row]

    return label
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    guard let label = pickerView.view(forRow: row, forComponent: component) as? UILabel else {
        return
    }
    label.backgroundColor = .orange
}
```

Answer (score 3):

// CGRectMake values for the frame we’d like

```
UIPickerView *myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];

// add the UIPickerView to your viewcontroller [mainView addSubview:myPickerView];

// set the selectionindicator to none myPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = NO;
```

// define the image that we would like to use

```
UIImage *selectorImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selectionIndicator.png"];

UIView *customSelector = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:selectorImage];
```

// set the x and y values to the point on the UIPickerView where you want to place the image

// set the width and height values to the width and height of your image

```
customSelector.frame = CGRectMake(10,(myPickerView.bounds.size.height / 2) + 16, self.view.bounds.size.width – 10, 47);
```

// add the custom selectionIndicator also to the same viewcontroller

```
[mainView addSubview:customSelector];
```

Comment: but if you add your own selection you should somehow hide the existing one

Answer (score 2):

Call the `UIPickerView` instance's `-viewForRow:forComponent:` method to get the `UIView *` object. Then set that view's background `UIColor`.

Comment: I  beleive I've tried that already, but I've give it another go

Comment: Also make sure you have set your UIView (containing the UIPickerView) as the pickerview's delegate, and that you have specified that the `UIView` will implement the `UIPickerViewDelegate` contract.

Comment: Hi Alex,

I've got the code above in the pickerviewcontroller and have set the pickerview.delegate = self in the loadView method.  I tried in the didSelectRow method:
UIView *selectedView = [numberFactsPicker viewForRow:numberRow forComponent:kFactComponent];
  
  selectedView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
  
somehow I think I would need to add it back as a subview maybe?

Comment: Maybe you can check if *selectedView is nil. Maybe something is not wired up right. Perhaps use the debugger or NSLog statements to check the values of things, as well as to make sure that your delegate methods are being called.

Comment: Setting the viewForRow's background color works-mostly but, in the case of the first and last item, you can still see the picker's white background, "off the edge of the reel."

Sadly, setting [myPickerView setBackGroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]] (or any color) doesn't do what one might hope.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear where you are putting the above code. Is it in `-pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:`? This is where it should be. Are you sure that you are maintaining a pointer to the label for that particular view? The fact that you are crashing suggests you probably are not. A larger block of code, including where you have put it, would be helpful.

Comment: Rob, I've posted the full method thanks again for any suggestions!

Comment: I think you've misunderstood how this delegate methods works. The pickerView is giving you a `reusingView`. You're modifying it with `-addSubView:`, but you're returning a different view (the `UILabel`). The first thing you should do here is get rid of the calls to `-addSubView:`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

1. Add a `UIView` as a subview to your `UIPickerView`
2. Constrain it to be Y entered with your `UIPickerView` and the has the same width
3. Give it height equal to the height of what returned in `pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat`
4. Make it semi transparent and color it the way you want

*the rest of the solutions (with custom views for row or attributed stringsfor row) were buggy when scrolling fast.

Answer (score 0):

UIPickerView has delegate to set NSAttributeString for title at row and component we can set attribute color like below:

```
- (NSAttributedString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView attributedTitleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    NSDictionary *attrs = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor]};
    NSString *title = @"title"
    return [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title attributes:attrs];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Alessandro Pirovano's answer;

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    UILabel *labelSelected = (UILabel*)[pickerView viewForRow:row forComponent:component];
    [labelSelected setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    labelSelected.superview.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
}
```

Comment: This works as expected for me. Text label has color and also the row background has color. Only caveat is, you need to force the selection when you create the picker view so that the initial display also has the selected row with colors.