# how to change the default color of selection bar in PickerView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uipickerview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change color of selected row in UIPickerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895830/how-to-change-color-of-selected-row-in-uipickerview)

I have taken a pickerview in my application but client doesn't like the default color of the selection bar of the pickerview and he wants greenish shade instead of default color. I repeat  I want to change the color of selection bar only not entire pickerview.

pls tell me how can I change the color of selection bar only

Comment: Are you looking for something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958443/overriding-highlighted-selection-in-uipickerview/1433901#1433901?