# PickerView Can't Change Color Of 2nd Row

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I use picker view in textfield input view. it works perfectly but when I selected the second row then it changes the color red and then I close picker and when I open second-time picker color of the selected row is not changed but it's not working only for second row .other row works perfectly.

Here is MyCode

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {    
var selectedRow = String()
selectedRow = capicityArray[row]
let pickerLabel = UILabel()

if pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: component) == row {
            pickerLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: selectedRow, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font:GlobalFont.Font_GillSansStd(fontsize: 26), NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: GlobalColor.RED_THEME])

        } else {
            pickerLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: selectedRow, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font:GlobalFont.Font_GillSansStd(fontsize: 22), NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: GlobalColor.Color153])
        }
        pickerLabel.isOpaque = true
        pickerLabel.textAlignment = .center
        return pickerLabel
    }
```

output :

When First time Selected 2nd row

[image]

then close picker and open picker again the [image] 
the second-row not change color red

Comment: see this link : - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895830/how-to-change-color-of-selected-row-in-uipickerview

Comment: this is happennig because each time you are creating new object of label

Comment: @RahulGUsai when I declare global variable of a label that time picker view does not display any row

Comment: You want your selected row as red, only selected row right?

Comment: @ReinierMelian Yes

Answer (score 0):

Use `didSelectRow` method of `UIPickerViewDelegate` and change your font color and font size there

**UPDATE**

I had added this code to selection, to avoid code repeat

```
func applySelection(pickerView : UIPickerView, row:Int, component:Int) {
        if let selectedView = pickerView.view(forRow: row, forComponent: component)  as? UILabel {
            selectedView.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: (selectedView.attributedText?.string)!, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font:GlobalFont.Font_GillSansStd(fontsize: 26), NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: GlobalColor.RED_THEME])
        }
    }
```

**Fixing the preselected issue**

You can simply add this code in your `viewDidAppear` or when you show your pickerView

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.applySelection(pickerView: self.pickerView, row: 0, component: 0)
}
```

**Then you can use it like this**

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {

        let pickerLabel = UILabel()
        pickerLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: capicityArray[row], attributes: attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font:GlobalFont.Font_GillSansStd(fontsize: 22), NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: GlobalColor.Color153])
        pickerLabel.isOpaque = true
        pickerLabel.textAlignment = .center
        return pickerLabel
    }

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        self.applySelection(pickerView: pickerView, row: row, component: component)
    }
```

Comment: it's Code Working when we Select Row but what about the preselected row.

Comment: @darshdixit did my answer finally help you?

Comment: no, because I am not said preselected when clicking first time in picker view. I said preselected when we clicking a second time in picker view that time picker view should display a selected row of last time selected row.  @ReinierMelian

Comment: well sorry, I don't understand quite well, you need the color in the preselected row only? @darshdixit